# php zip freezes the computer and makes many zip files

Tags: php, download, zip, freeze, php-ziparchive

i'm trying to make a download site to my watch online site
i need the download site turns the videos into zip files before download it to the user then delete it, but some times when i click on the download button the whole computer freezes and it need to force shutdown to turn off , and some times it kind of work but it makes at least 5 to 8 zip files and delete it except 1 ,
this is my zip.php file (downloading file)

```
<?php
$type = isset($_GET['type']) ? filter_var($_GET['type'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : '';
if ($type = 'zip') {
    include '../inc/config.php';
    $series = filter_var($_GET['series'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $episode = filter_var($_GET['episode'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $get_series_name = $db->prepare('SELECT name FROM serieses WHERE ID = ?');
    $get_series_name->execute(array($series));
    $seriesInfo = $get_series_name->fetch();
    $file_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/AnimeSite/Serieses/'. $seriesInfo['name'] .'/'. $episode .'.mp4';
    $zip_name = $seriesInfo['name'] .' - Ep '. $episode . '.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        $zip->addFile($file_path, $seriesInfo['name'].' - '. $episode .'.mp4');
        $zip->close();
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
    if(file_exists($zip_name)){
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-type: application/zip');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'. $zip_name .'"');
        header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header("Content-length: ". filesize('C:\xampp\htdocs\DownloadSite\comp\\' . $zip_name) ."");
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($zip_name);
        sleep(20);
        unlink('C:\xampp\htdocs\DownloadSite\comp\\' . $zip_name);
    }
    ?>
    <div id="thank-msg">
        <p>
            <i class="fa fa-check-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Downloading ...
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
} else {
    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: PHP is server-side, so that isn't what is making your computer freeze. It is what is rendered client-side that is giving you a problem. You're using *local* file paths instead of *server* file paths so this: `$file_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/AnimeSite/Serieses/'. $seriesInfo['name'] .'/'. $episode .'.mp4';` is wrong.

Comment: I'm a bit curious: why putting the file into a zip file?

Comment: @spectras to reduce its size

Comment: @JayBlanchard but it some times work, and the file download correctly , and what the right way to write the file path in this case

Comment: PHP should be using relative file paths because it acts on the server. While the local file system is available to PHP, because you're using your local system as the server, you should change the paths in such a way that they would work on a remote web server. For example `$file_path = 'AnimeSite/Serieses/'. $seriesInfo['name'] .'/'. $episode .'.mp4';`

Comment: @MohamedGaber> unless it was **really** badly encoded, you won't reduce the size of an mp4 file with zip. Your mp4s hold an already compressed format, with better compression than zip for video as it takes advantage of its specialized knowledge of video data redundancy. Try it yourself, I highly doubt you save more than 2 or 3% on the size (and some videos may even get *larger* when zipped).

Comment: it seems like you are right @spectras it's better to download the video itself than the zip